# PDF to CAMT (XML/MT940) conversion

Tags: pdf, xml, conversion

Is there someone who can provide any information about converting PDF documents to the CAMT, appropriate XML or MT940 format?
Target OS is a windows 10 machine.
I appreciate any useful information.